# Change first 200 record in a column into sequent

Tags: mysql, sql

What I try to do is to make the first 200 records from a column to start from 1 to 200. After 200 records no changing on values.
The current records look like this

```
1
2
3
4
4
6
6
...
```

What I need is to update them to be

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
200
```

What sql statement do I need to fix them?

Comment: I didn't really understand your need. Could you try giving more details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a [user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and do it like this:

```
SET @rownumber = 0;
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column = (@rownumber := @rownumber + 1)
ORDER BY the_column_that_defines_the_order_of_the_first_200_records
LIMIT 200;
```